# Is it possible to lose weight on some special parts of body?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, legs, thigh

I'm 165 cm tall and I weigh 56 kg.

I'm the ideal weight for my height now, but don't like my body and what it looks like!

I'd love to be skinny but I don't know how.

Fat tummy, belly, leg ..

I am, as you have probably noticed, very nervous about this.

Any ideas?

I want to know what's wrong with me and how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Hi @Gigili, I have to disappoint you, you can't 'target' fat loss. [This question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast) and [have both addressed that](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/how-to-lose-fat-only-in-your-thigh). Instead, I think we should give you advice on how to *tone* your body

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you are the ideal weight for your height.  I'm assuming you mean according to the BMI measure.  Your example would be the other reason I dislike that measure.  BMI is a general indicator of someone who would be obese or underweight.  It is by no means accurate, nor does it take into account your body fat.

So, while you can't target where your body burns fat, what you can do is change the proportions of muscle and fat at your weight.  Your body is really good at maintaining weight, so that's the easy part.

For you I would recommend exercise.  Do something you love that will challenge your muscles.  Challenging the muscles causes them to grow, and since you'll be using more energy you'll have less fat to boot.  In essence, you'll be lean but muscular.

Here's some potential ideas:

- Kayaking (a friend of mine loves this)
- Rock climbing
- Swimming
- Running (you'll lose fat, but you're only going to put muscle on where you use it--your legs)
- Dance
- Strength training
- Martial arts
- Boxing

And the list goes on.  Since you aren't trying to lose weight, you probably won't have to do too much to your diet.  Now it's just about getting active.

Comment: All kinds of sports would be suitable? I, personally, love basketball.

Comment: Anything that gets you active will help shed the excess fat.  Basketball would be great.  Of course, putting in the sprints and court work exercises also helps improve your cardio and muscle tone.  Like running, you'll lose fat, but most of your muscle gains are going to be in your legs.

Comment: @Gigili Body Fat % is a far better indicator. and it's good to lose excess fat but to achieve and toned, fit look you'll need to build some muscles too

Answer (score 3):

When you eat excessively, you can't decide where your body should store fat. So when your try to lose weight or burn fat, again you can't decide which part of your body should lose weight first.