# I need an advice about a training

Tags: diet, workout, training, bellyfat, burn-fat

I'm new here.
I'm 67kg and I'm fine with my body, it's pretty normal, but I don't like 2 things. The problem is that I have a hard belly and my bum looks big from a side.
What should I eat or do? Any advice? (I don't eat much by the way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this prior post ([How to lose fat only in your thigh?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/how-to-lose-fat-only-in-your-thigh)) you really can't spot/target reduce fat.  What you can do is go on a diet plan and develop a workout plan specific to those areas you want to increase muscle in.  The most difficult area (for a man) to reduce fat is the stomach/oblique area.  Steps to success:

- keep a food diary for 1-2 weeks and review your intake and determine you daily intake
- determine what your daily caloric goal should be (http://caloriecount.about.com/cc/calories-goal.php)
- adjust your diet appropiately
- develop a combo weight/cardio workout routine (search [bodybuilding.com](http://bodybuilding.com))
- check your progress every 3-4 weeks

good luck

Comment: Thank you. It's a stupid question, but how to lose fat on my bum?

Comment: By losing fat everywhere @blez

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: but the strange thing is that I don't even eat much. It's maybe cause I'm working as programmer and I sit all day.

Comment: Indeed, you may not eat much, but you exercise even less @blez. The solution is to exercise more, because eating less isn't fun and might result in a lack of nutrition.