# Flat abdomen without losing fat from face

Tags: weight-loss, abdominals

I am trying to reduce my abdominal fat so that I can see my abs :) currently my BMI is around 22, which is a normal weight, I do Running and weight training every alternate day, and to reduce weight seems to be easy, but problem is as I reduce weight further I see more effect on my face than abdomen, I feel abdomen is within reach (about 1 inch fat) but I am scared to reduce weight lest my face will look too skinny.

So is there any way to reduce fat from abdomen without loosing fat from face?

Comment: Maybe you just look more tired or you're dehydrated. If you're BMI is where you say I doubt your face has a lot of excess fat, unless you have a big underhang below your chin. What areas of your face seem to be getting "skinnier"?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't target your fat loss to a particular region. See these answers for more details:

- [How to lose fat only in your thigh?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/how-to-lose-fat-only-in-your-thigh/1301#1301)
- [What are the true implications of the abdominals being actually just one muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/what-are-the-true-implications-of-the-abdominals-being-actually-just-one-muscle/3405#3405)