# Best way to reduce side belly fat?

Tags: exercise, weight-loss

I have a lot of fat on the sides of my belly above my waist, and keeps increasing the more I eat.

**Question:** What's the best way to reduce the fat here, though I do have fat in the belly and chest areas, but the side belly fat is putting me off.. :)

Comment: You seem to subscribe to the [spot reduction myth](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3933/1771). Unfortunately, it's not feasible to target fat loss. You need to lose fat all over. The good news: fixing your diet and increasing exercise works well for this goal.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with others who have commented that you have to target fat loss all over.  While exercise can be somewhat helpful, fat loss is probably 90% diet so you should focus your effort there.  Many have had success with relative ease using Tim Ferriss's [Slow Carb Diet](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2012/06/24/how-to-lose-100-pounds/) so I would recommend that you give you that a try.

Answer (score 0):

While the popular notion is that spot reduction is a myth, there are plenty of popular notions that are wrong, so it might still be worth exploring.

Bud Jeffries has an [article](http://www.strongerman.com/fat-burning-isometrics/) on using isometrics for spot reduction. I'd say it's worth a shot, as isometric exercises make a lot of sense for the core and even if it doesn't work out you end up a lot stronger.

On the other hand, unless there's a particular reason why you want to keep your belly and chest fat, you might as well go for getting rid of it all.