# Can I add in some core exercises to SL 5x5 and what do you suggest if so?

Tags: strength, abdominals, stronglifts, core

I don't really think that my core is being worked enough when performing the compound lifts of strong lifts, as the rest of my body has caught up while my stomach and waist are still really flabby and have no real firmness comparatively. I'm not asking "what exercise do I do to reduce stomach fat", I'm asking if I can add in some cable crunches and another auxiliary exercise to strengthen and firm my core for other lifts and if so what would you suggest?

As I understand exercises like sit ups and laying crunches and other variations(leg raises) are limited mostly by the inability to use weight above your body weight effectively so weighted exercises for abs/core are recommended.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the L-sit. (will write a full answer later if I get the chance) It seems deceptively easy, and might even have carryover to other exercises later (L-sit pullups anyone?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to believe the [spot reduction myth](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3933/1771). Cable crunches and other ab work for strength and endurance will have **no measurable effect** on your belly and waist flabbiness.

Secondly, the squat, deadlift, and overhead press are all core exercises, and quite good ones. If you're not getting enough work now, you will soon, because you're adding weight each workout. It's not possible to have a weak core and squat or deadlift heavy.

Therefore I recommend adding no additional core exercises to StrongLifts 5x5.

Comment: For the poster in question I agree with everything you've said, however those 3 exercises alone won't give you the proper balance of ab and erector strength. So at some point core exercises are needed to keep your core in balance.

Comment: "I'm not asking "what exercise do I do to reduce stomach fat"" - OP

Comment: Any further input? I was asking for strength purposes, not to "spot reduce". As these guys said.

Comment: @Hituptony "as the rest of my body has caught up while my stomach and waist are still really flabby". I don't think there's a tremendous imbalance, and though there's nothing wrong with ab work I don't think the OP should worry about any at the moment.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce For strength purposes, add weight to your squat and overhead press and make sure you're keeping good form, i.e. nice and tight through the abs during those lifts. Accessory work is not really necessary when you're not yet using a bunch of weight in the primary lifts. Furthermore, you're right at that place in the progression where people often simultaneously A) get bored and want to monkey with the program and B) start to lift challenging weights, meaning they need to double down on the fundamentals instead of adding new stuff.

Comment: Consider, he may be doing the additional core work on off-days? I mean I know the question says add, but that's like saying don't do cardio on off days. Abs/Core take under 10 minutes to do if done properly. Instead of saying NO NO OFF LIMITS you could say in moderation. I don't believe his progress will be hindered if he does planks on off-days, or went for a nice jog around town...

Comment: @Hituptony There are valid ways and reasons to add accessory work, including core (or, in this case, ab) exercises. But I don't think this particular person should do so.

Comment: I see, well as his virtual personal trainer, you may know best...I digress.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann One of the main draws I had to SL 5x5 was the 45 minute workout time, but now since things are getting a little tough, the rest time between heavy(relatively)sets is really drawing out the length of the workout to 1.5 hours easily. Is this normal?

Comment: @Hituptony My friend...this is a question and answer site. *He asked*, so I answered. You commented with your opinion and that's cool. Ideally you'd post your own answer with your opinion. Maybe you're more right than me, but all I did was respond to your comment explaining why I answered the way I did.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Totally normal. 5 minutes between challenging lifts is normal. Personally I switch to different programming if the workout hits 2 hours due to >5 minute rests.

Comment: What do you suggest? I would like to do it but I'm not sure I'm at the "level" to be doing SL 3x5 yet? Or could I be wrong? I typically don't need 5 minutes until my 4th or 5th squat, and the OHP has been incredibly hard. One day I'll pump out the sets easily and then when I go to increase the weight, the 5lb minimal increase will be extremely challenging in comparison. I'll try 2-3 minute rests but sometimes I feel that even that isn't enough. On a typical squat for me I'll do final warmup-2-min-Set-2min-Set-3min-Set-4min-Set-5min-Set.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Ask a new question using those two comments. It's a great question.

Comment: Okay, I'll get it posted.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best core exercise is a prone bridge. You can also do side bridges for more emphasis on the obliques.

Comment: I agree, you can add core training exercises to your program. I do deadlifts, squats, military press, and 3 days a week I opt for some weighted crunches. 80lbs of resistance for 80-100 reps. Just do it til you can't.