# please help me i am suffering from fat chest!

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, chest

I am a 17 year old, 12th grade student. I weigh 78 kgs and am 5 feet 5 inches tall.

I am a good student but I could have done 100 times better if I did not have moobs.

I want to lose chest fat, otherwise i will be dammed and i can't concentrate on anything. I try a lot to concentrate but resulting in partial concentration.

I have spent hours in just searching what is the best way to lose fats on my chest. I am going to appear for JEE (joint entrance exam) which is a serious exam and requires full concentration I have a time of around 10 months, but I don't want to delay, I want to make me lean and thin around all parts of my body. Most of the fats are settled around my thigh.

Please help me get rid of this. Give me a clear cut solution, without going for surgery. I don't want to tell anybody about it, it's so shameful and I don't want to go to gym. I want to do home exercises. Sometimes it makes me think I am a fat girl due to my fat body, if I did have masculine body I would have been feeling great like a strong man. I searched everything in internet, some say if I lose fats on my belly by kapalbhatti then my moobs will look bigger.

I tried doing pushups, some say that will not just help
you need to do gazillion of exercises. Some say nothing will work except surgery. So I am mad at this, I don't know which is correct and proven method to work.After all what i need is masculine body alongside great concentration and brain power. what i can do is pushups and think it will gonna work. I am completely vegan and avoid oily foods, no spices just simple diet three times a day. Please tell me a cleat cut formula that will work and definitely work, I have a time of 1 month to reduce all my body fat.

Comment: Err this kind of question attracts spam answers! Flag to protect?

Comment: And you _should_ go to gym! Its good for you

Comment: i will choose good answer by most reputed person.

Comment: @UniKitty moreover my papa will not agree to send me to gym.

Comment: Don't do that. Choose what fits you best. A new user with no rep may give the best, not a mod

Comment: @helpseeker - Honestly, if you are blaming lack of academic performance on your obsession with your body, then you also need to talk to a counselor. Body dysmorphia is a recognizable, treatable condition. And if you keep obsessing over your outward appearance, it leads to other maladies, possibly anorexia, etc. If you want to improve your appearance that's great, but you can't let it derail your life, either.

Answer (score 3):

1) [You can't spot reduce](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/how-to-lose-fat-only-in-your-thigh). Your body stores fat all over (and inside) of you in a ratio that's tied to your DNA. There's nothing you can do to target fat in any particular area.

2) You should get evaluated on your "moobs" to determine if you have [gynecomastia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia) (nicknamed: gyno ... like guy-no).

3) [Most of your body fat deposits have to do with how much you eat, not how much you workout](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117).

You need to follow these steps, and you won't be able to achieve success in 1 month. It took you a long time to get fat, it will take you a long time to get it off. Accept that reality and if you can't than accept that your impatience is going to keep you on a train to obesity and endocrine disfunction.

- [Track every thing you eat for two weeks](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/), no exceptions.
- [Get an idea on how many calories you should eat](http://www.mayoclinic.org/calorie-calculator/itt-20084939).
- Start a [strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/aerobic-vs-anaerobic-for-better-fat-loss/19117#19117). Since you don't have access to a gym, you'll need to do [bodyweight activity](http://www.exrx.net/Questions/BasicProgram.html). Consider buying a [good book](http://amzn.to/1JMQPt2) on the subject.

Honestly, there is no secret to having a "manly body". It requires keeping track of your calories, constant effective exercising, and the discipline to prioritize fitness like you would going to the bathroom or taking a shower. Most people know this, but they look for quick fixes because being healthy and fit is a lifelong commitment.

> Please tell me a cleat cut formula that will work and definitely work,
>   I have a time of 1 month to reduce all my body fat.

Again, you can't in one month, sorry but that's reality. The clear cut formula is to be in a calorie deficit (eat ~200 calories a day less than you are using) and do balanced strength training 3-6 days a week. Do that and barring specific (and rare) medical problems you'll notice serious differences to your physical and mental self within 3-6 months.

Comment: I am not eating any oily food but how many pushups should i do to lose my fat? i think just sitting up without doing anything and eating less calories would not suffice my fat burning program! would it?

Comment: @helpseeker Bro, **his answer is spot on**. It looks like you can't accept the cold harsh fact of life. The last thing you **should not** be doing is to starve yourself and inevitably become anorexic.

Comment: I would just add, in general, that strength training is one possible exercise method, but really, anything that gets you up and moving for about a half hour gets you 90% of the way, and it's more important that you enjoy your exercise than that it's the most efficient form.