# Good exercises for lower pecs without weights

Tags: push-ups, upper-body-workout, chest

*Note: I'm just trying to get in shape over the summer while I'm away from school so I'm an amateur when it comes to physical fitness and I might not know what I'm talking about.*

As of right now I'm just working out at home with out using any weights and I've been trying to do some pecs exercises (**specifically to trim down chest fat, man boobs if you will**). I found a couple pages online stating that pushups (regular style) are one of the best exercises you can do without weights so that's what I've been doing. The only problem is that so far I haven't noticed much of a change. Now I know building muscle takes time but the pushups in particular raise concern because I've notice significant changes in the other areas of my body that I've been working out (with other exercises) for just as long. Before coming to stack exchange to discuss this I talked to a friend of mine about the situation. I asked him if I was doing anything wrong or if there's a specific exercise to burn chest fat. Now I'm not sure how correct his response is but he told me something along the lines of,

> Regular pushups will build your **upper pec**. Whereas I need something that works my **lower pec** in order to burn chest fat.

He didn't know of any lower pec exercises that could be done without weights off the top of his head so I ended up googling it. This is where my problem lies, I found a number of different webpages all saying a number of different things.

Some examples of things that were suggested are:

Elevated push ups

[image: Elevated Push ups]

Or

Clapping push ups

[image: Clapping Push ups]

Ultimately my question is:

**What is the best exercise to burn chest fat (without the use of weights)?**

Or are the above examples acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right off the bat, [you can't reduce fat from any particular part of your body](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/1301/7091). *Spot reduction is a myth.*

Most of the chest exercises you're looking at will build your chest proportionally. In general, the more [inclined](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralClavicular/BBInclineBenchPress.html) a movement (closer to over your head), the higher the pec area will be used. The more declined the movement is, like in [dips](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BWChestDip.html), the lower the pec area.

You'll see the support for that on exrx's muscle tar getting for various incline/decline movements.

Just to tuck it in there, you should have [a balanced strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091). You'll never have a truly developed chest unless the rest of you is pretty muscular as well. Worse, unbalanced strength training can lead you to injury land. And as a bonus, [good strength training programs will really assist your fat loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19117/7091).

Comment: Awesome, so far I believe I'm on the right track of a balanced strength training program, but the page you listed will definitely help. Also just to be clear, the way to burn chest fat would be to reduce overall body fat as a whole? Meaning as long as I'm losing fat (with a good mix of strength training), my chest will also gradually go down as well?

Comment: @PaulWarnick , yep you're totally right. Good strength training all around and keep the diet in check: you're on the road to yoked.